# How to download similar pages?

Tags: pdf, download, download-manager, ebook

There is a website that has pdf book or article inside it. for example

https://example.com/cgi/imgsrv/download/pdf?id=mdp.39015015603924;orient=0;size=100;seq=1;attachment=0

and the other pages differ only in "seq=".

Is there any way or software to generate all pages and download it.
Thanks.

Comment: There are many different ways, but you are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this app:

[MetaProducts Offline Explorer](https://www.datafilehost.com/d/e6393767)

Or use IDM

[image: IDM Grabber]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably cumbersome compared to other approaches, but this perl script ought to do the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $seq = 1;
my $maxseq = 100;

while($seq <= $maxseq)
{
  my $cmdstring = 'wget https://example.com/cgi/imgsrv/download/pdf?id=mdp.39015015603924;orient=0;size=100;seq=' . $seq . ';attachment=0';
  print `$cmdstring`;
  $seq++
}
```

grab hold of a perl interpreter and a port of wget for your system, and it'll download all the files, starting at `seq=1`, ending at `seq=100`. Should work fine for similar cases with other URLs, just replace the URL in the `while`-loop, and change the `$seq` and `$maxseq` to whatever you want.

**Disclaimer:** I have not tested it, as I do not have perl on my current machine. If there are any problems, they should be easily fixable.

Comment: What's the idea behind using Perl as a launcher for `wget`? You can do the same in any shell.

Comment: @techraf Possibly, but I write perl more fluently than I write bash. And as I said, there are probably plenty of approaches that are less cumbersome than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the batch downloader [WFDownloader App](https://wfdownloader.000webhostapp.com/). Open the app, go to Tasks -> Add batch download with pattern. Next, specify the range on your link in square brackets like so seq=[1-50].

The url now looks like this ...example.com/cgi/imgsrv/download/pdf?id=mdp.39015015603924;orient=0;size=100;seq=[1-50];attachment=0.

Click confirm and then use the Start button to begin the downloads in a batch. 
Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot here]